# Accessing the models removed from an association in a callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many: :widgets
  has_many: :grommits, through: :widgets

  after_save {
    do_something_on_the_grommits_that_have_been_removed
  }
end
```

I want to know which members of the association have been removed in an after_save callback, so I can do something to them. The after_remove callback is not ideal, as I'd like the logic to work however the objects are removed, not just in a specific way (after_remove will only work if that association is manipulated directly).

Is this possible?

Comment: Would association callbacks accomplish what you're looking for? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/association_basics.html#association-callbacks

Comment: @JoshBrody - not reliably. They only fire when a change is made directly to the association they are on. In the case above, removing a widget will have the affect of removing a grommit, but the association callback on grommits won't be fired